# Spring cloud data flow Httpclient

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have the following stream.
**Context of the problem**

1.

```
rabbit --password='******' --queues=springdataflow-q --virtual-host=springdataflow --host=172.24.172.184 --username=springdataflow | transform | httpclient --url-expression='http://172.20.24.47:8080/push' --http-method=POST --headers-expression={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} --body-expression={arg1:payload} | log
```

2.

I have spring boot running locally.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {



    @RequestMapping(value = "/push", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = {MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
      public String pushMessage(@RequestParam(value="arg1") String payload) {
        System.out.println(payload);
        return payload;
      } 
}
```

3. I would like to have the rabbit message come into `httpclient` as value for the the 'arg1' parameter value to the post request. The intent being that message published on rabbit queue is consumed by a rest post point, the message being captured by SpEL payload.

For this I am using the `body-expression = {arg1:payload}` but this is not working, maybe syntactically wrong.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The `@RequestParam(value="arg1")` is really about request param, the part of the URL after `?`, which is called `query string`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string.

So, if you really would like to have an `arg1=payload` pair in the query string, you need to use a proper `url-expression`:

```
--url-expression='http://172.20.24.47:8080/push?arg1='+payload
```

Comment: Yes using this works, now although If I publish message to rabbit 'this is a test' I am getting an ascii version in the log-sink : 2018-08-08 21:35:16.210  INFO 28592 --- [           -L-2] log-sink                                 : 116,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,116,101,115,116

Comment: I think on my rest controller @RestController
public class HelloController {



    @RequestMapping(value = "/push", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = {MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
      public String pushMessage(@RequestParam(value="arg1") String payload) {
        System.out.println(payload);
        return payload;
      } 
} I think I have to change the MediaType ?

Comment: Thank a lot now just need to figure out to how get string as is from rabbit all the way to httpclient and then log

Comment: It must be not `produces`, but `consumes`

Comment: Ok lets say I change produces to consumes {MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN} do I need to remove this --headers-expression={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} from the httpclient parameter ?

Comment: So I tried this :@RequestMapping(value = "/push", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes ={MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
   public String pushMessage(@RequestParam(value="arg1") String payload) {
     System.out.println(payload);
     return payload;
   }  removed  --headers-expression   Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported]
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:219)

Comment: OK. I believe you don't need  neither `consumes`, nor `produces`. What you need is something like `--inputType=text/plain` for the `httpclient` processor

Comment: sure will try this, i will check if there is a field inputType exposed on httpclient processor, else I could use --headers-expression={'Content-Type':'text/plain'} and remove consumes and produces entirely on the rest post method.

Comment: You also need to have an `--inputType=text/plain` on the `log` sink as well, I believe...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work to pass strings as payloads. It seems that by default the payload becomes requestbody. 
So on the rest service I made a change:
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pushbody", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
      public String  pushBody(@RequestBody String payload) {
        System.out.println(payload);
        return payload;
      }

And the stream that seems to work now is :
rabbit --password='******' --queues=springdataflow-q1 --host=172.24.172.184 --virtual-host=springdataflow --username=springdataflow | httpclient --http-method=POST --headers-expression={'Content-Type':'text/plain'} --url=http://172.20.24.47:8080/pushbody | log

I did try with inputType= text/plain suggestion both on httpclient and logsink and removing the consumes and produces on the rest service post method,  but no luck there.